# pthread_mutex_init return EOPNOTSUPP(95) with qemu aarch64

Tags: debugging, pthreads, qemu, arm64, qemu-device

I have tried to run with qemu-aarch64 process. And I see that the `pthread_mutex_init` return EOPNOTSUPP(95)

Maybe qemu-aarch64 makes a problem and I should debug that process into real aarch64 machine?(how can I do that?)

Comment: This is most likely about your C library (inside the virtual machine), not particularly tied to the fact that it is a virtual machine rather than a real one.  That C library seems not to support pthreads mutexes, and so probably not other pthreads functions either.  It provides stub implementations that always fail, which allows programs to deal gracefully with the situation.  If you want to use pthreads then you need a C library that will support it.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are trying to initialize a mutex with non-default attributes, then it might be the specific combination of mutex attributes that is being rejected.  That should be pretty easy to check / test.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I used the libraries of the device I research. Those libraries works into the device,  I just tried to emulate with qemu-aarch in my PC

Comment: You don't say what version of QEMU you're using. Check if the issue is still there in the most recent version.